# Change Font size in align environment

Tags: fonts, spacing, overleaf, size

here is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}

\mathit{Set} \ x^0 \\
For \ i = 1 \ to \ N-1 \\
 &\phantom{{}= x^0} \mathit{Sample} \ x'\stackrel{}{\sim}g'(x'|x^0) \\
 &\phantom{{}= x^0}   \mathit{Sample} \ u\stackrel{}{\sim}U \in [0,1] \\
 &\phantom{{}= x^0}   A(x', x^0) = min(1, \frac{P(x') \ g(x^0| x')}{P(x^0) \ g(x'| x^0)}) \\
&\phantom{{}= x^0}   x^{(i+1)} = \Bigg\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                  x' \ if \ u<= A(x', x^0) \\
                    x^0 \ otherwhise 
                \end{array}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I know it's weird, but I want to tatoo this. I would like to have the

```
\frac{P(x') \ g(x^0| x')}{P(x^0) \ g(x'| x^0)}
```

a little bit bigger and add a vertical space between x^0 and x' in the bracket (just a little)

```
 \Bigg\{ \begin{array}{ll}
                      x' \ if \ u<= A(x', x^0) \\
                        x^0 \ otherwhise 
                    \end{array}
```

I am working with overleaf (I do not know if this can be helpful).
This is more or less what I want

[image]

Let me know! and Thanks for your answers

Comment: However it’s the metropolis-hastings algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

I try to cleanup your code:

- in math environments had not to be empty lines
- `min` is operator, hence it should be write as `\min`
- text in equation should be (usual) in text mode, so write it inside of a `\text{ ... }`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
\text{Set }  x^0
    &   \\
\text{For } i 
    & = 1 \text{ to } N-1                      \notag  \\
    & \text{Sample }   x' \sim g'(x'\mid x^0)          \\
    & \text{Sample }   u  \sim U \in [0,1]             \\
    & A(x', x^0) = \min\left(1,\dfrac{P(x')  g(x^0 \mid x' )}
                                  {P(x^0) g(x'  \mid x^0)}\right) \\
    &  x^{(i+1)} = \begin{dcases}
                  x'    & \text{if } u \leq A(x', x^0) \\
                  x^0   & \text{otherwise}
                \end{dcases}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```